# using R to make a heatmap for a data frame with specification

Tags: r

I need help making a heatmap, please.

I want to make a heatmap of this dataset (the dataset is larger but this will show the structure):

data.str <-
structure(
list(
Metabolite = c(
"Glucose_%",
"Fructose_%",
"Sugars_%",
"Sugars.as.mono_%",
"Starch_%",
"Starch.as.mono_%",
"Glutamic_%",
"Proline_%",
"Biotin_%",
"C20.2cn6_%"
),
Difference_S_HDL_CE_pct = c(
27.0580967,
29.4741588,
30.6727965,
37.044534,
0.00592,
0.00924,
2.8089622,
4.3284966,
3.616572,
16.6234106
),
Difference_L_HDL_TG = c(
20.3426932,
19.6578323,
6.1540709,
6.618907,
20.7397107,
22.7363078,
5.7014121,
6.0341221,
5.9002733,
5.0788391
),
Difference_Gln = c(
20.2203384,
21.9353406,
17.1303398,
17.3148438,
8.7804598,
7.0612042,
0.5848933,
0.3856946,
0.0748362,
10.761994
),
Difference_S_LDL_FC_pct = c(
20.1171041,
21.1194979,
19.0084278,
22.7941105,
0.6624931,
1.2516315,
0.4276689,
1.3559095,
1.7227713,
18.2480865
),
Difference_Pyruvate = c(
17.5854511,
19.9410449,
12.7105925,
11.9623687,
10.4788242,
8.6559229,
0.0189435,
0.0239544,
0.00312,
16.7369868
),
Difference_L_LDL_TG = c(
13.250508,
13.9865028,
13.4782952,
14.1116228,
4.0569956,
3.3975936,
0.8144706,
0.7677175,
0.0572463,
14.4629904
),
Difference_S_HDL_C_pct = c(
12.9346568,
13.1410302,
16.6905244,
22.6788084,
1.7590544,
1.3980602,
2.9658478,
4.8456946,
2.7936213,
27.68029
),
Difference_S_HDL_PL_pct = c(
12.864684,
11.9193723,
10.8118128,
11.8431789,
1.0692856,
1.4855054,
1.9670692,
1.3530411,
8.5227632,
-1.6739852
),
Difference_M_LDL_TG_pct = c(
12.8530009,
11.4667269,
13.5677286,
16.3305456,
0.9506285,
0.5322617,
0.8908791,
1.898937,
2.9490729,
29.5990618
),
Difference_L_LDL_C_pct = c(
12.5509812,
13.624991,
12.482877,
13.1641219,
0.3197067,
0.0195839,
8.7725257,
7.2044468,
0.0122509,
8.4407425
),
Difference_IDL_TG = c(
12.0014,
11.378059,
6.0707129,
6.2593626,
8.3150096,
9.6032892,
4.2182798,
3.8636934,
4.2984429,
1.8889026
)
),
row.names = c(NA, 10L),
class = "data.frame"
)

the maximum value I have is around 40, so I want the scale to be between -2 and 45. The color is red and the darker is the higher is the value.

this is a good example of what I'm looking for
[image]

the only difference is that I want it red, scale from -2 to 40 and I want to divide the variables on the y-axis into subgroups (for example if I want to show that the lower three variables on the y-axis in this blue heatmap "col 1, col 10 and col 2" belong to a specific group like lipids, and each other 3 variables are from same subgroup like ratios, ketone bodies, etc.)

differences in metabolite should be on the y-axis and nutrients should be on x-axis. Also, I need values that are more than 5 to be printed on the corresponding square.

thank you in advance.

Comment: You can add the gaps with `pheatmap`: `library(pheatmap);library(colorspace);pheatmap::pheatmap(data.str,filename="1.png",cluster_rows=F,cluster_cols=F,gaps_col=c(3,7),breaks=seq(-2,40,42/256),legend_breaks=c(-2,20,40),border_color=NA,display_numbers=T,number_format="%.1f",number_color="white",colorRampPalette(colorspace::hex(HSV(0,.5,c(.2,1))))(256))`

Comment: You can display numbers bigger than 5 by adding `disp=round(data.str,1);disp[data.str<=5]=""` and adding the argument `display_numbers=disp`.

Comment: the question not answered yet. Please, if you can post an answer

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the existing answer ([How to create a simple heatmap in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953934/how-to-create-a-simple-heatmap-in-r)), you'll need to turn your data into a long format.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.str |>
    pivot_longer(everything()) |>
    group_by(name) |>
    mutate(row = row_number()) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = row, y = name, fill = value)) +
      geom_tile() +
      scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red", name = "Your Legend")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Harre. I just noticed I didn't bring the right structure. I amended the question and added some questions below the blue figure.